# parsing tab separated file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a tab separated file (`raw.txt`) which has format like :

```
type    A1    A2    A3    A4    ....
params  int   char  char  char  ...
data    1     abc   cde   fgh   ...
type    B1    B2    B3    B4    ....
feature int   char  char  char  ...
data    2     aaa   bbb   ccc   ...   
type    C1    C2    C3    C4    ....
stats   int   int   char  char  ...
data    2     11    aa    bb    ...
data    3     12    cc    cc    ...
data    4     13    dd    dd    ...
data    5     14    ee    ee    ...
...     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

I want to parse such file and then I wanted to  create a folder named of file name and then inside that folder, I want to create different files based on `types`. Files will be created with data once `type` observed in the line for example :

```
/raw/file1
A1    A2    A3    A4    ....
int   char  char  char  ...
1     abc   cde   fgh   ...

/raw/file2
B1    B2    B3    B4    ....
int   char  char  char  ...
2     aaa   bbb   ccc   ...

/raw/file3
C1    C2    C3    C4    ....
int   int   char  char  ...
2     11    aa    bb    ...
3     12    cc    cc    ...
4     13    dd    dd    ...
5     14    ee    ee    ...
...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

and so on...
and also i want to create dictionaries like,

```
dict1 = {A1:['int', [1]], A2:['char', ['abc']], ...}
dict2 = {B1:['int', [2]], B2:['char', ['aaa']], ...}
dict3 = {C1:['int', [2, 3, 4, 5], C2:['int', [11, 12, 13, 14, ...]], ...}
```

How can I do that because this is a very big file and parsing such huge file hangs the window and also I am not able to figure out how can I get such output from the file.

Comment: What is the code you have so far that "hangs the window" ?

Comment: I am iterating the file in the command prompt which hangs command prompt and I didnt able to understand the code which will give me such output.

Comment: It's hard to tell what lines you want to filter.  Generally, you should do a for loop, and split each line by ('\t'), then do something with the lines that start with whatever type you want to filter.

Comment: filtering is based on the "type" in the line

Comment: take a step back and split your problem in small subproblems, it looks like you are trying to 1) parse the file into an in-memory data structure 2) make the data column based, instead of row based, which is how you'd read it in and 3) dump the column based data in new files?

Comment: yes absolutely right. but if i parse column based how can i get rows in the file as i shown in the output

Comment: I have the necessary code to generate the files you want.  I haven't worked on the dictionary portion of it yet.  What are your intentions for the dictionary?  Are you going to pickle it for later use?

Comment: no i wanted dicts because data was more. it wl b ok if i can work with files too.

Comment: @EricRoper : can you let me know how to generate those files?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to parse the file and generate the new files.  The `newfile` list temporarily stores the data for each type before writing to file.  A line that starts with `'type'` will trigger newfile to store results for that type and if there were contents in `newfile` before it will write them to file.  The `inc` variable is incremented each time you make a call to `writefile()` and is used as the suffix for the filename.  In `writefile()` I used `str.format()` to create a dynamic file name and also to write to file left justified with a width of 6 taking arbitrarily many values from `linelist`.

```
def writefile(newfilelist, suffix):
  with open('file{}'.format(suffix), 'w') as f:
    for linelist in newfilelist:
      f.write(('{:<6}'*len(linelist)).format(*linelist) + '\n')

import os
with open('raw.txt') as file:
  os.mkdir('raw')
  os.chdir('raw')
  newfile = []
  inc = 0
  for line in file:
    linelist = line.split()
    if linelist[0] == 'type':
      if newfile:
        inc += 1
        writefile(newfile,inc)
        newfile = []
      newfile.append(linelist[1:])
    else:
      newfile.append(linelist[1:])
  if newfile:
    inc += 1
    writefile(newfile,inc)
```

Comment: it dont create multiple files. from above example, there should had 3 files but it creates only one

Comment: @sam: What version of python are you using? What is the name of the output file?

Comment: i am using python 2.7. i tried again it only create one file named file1 but it should create 3 files.

Comment: It sounds like in your program `if linelist[0] == 'type'` evaluates to false.  I copied and pasted the snippet you posted and saved it as 'raw.txt' to test the program.  Is the first column you posted with 'type', 'params', 'data', 'type', 'feature', ... actually in raw.txt?  Or did you add it as a description?